# PHP wget link through javascript call

Tags: php, linux, wget, simple-html-dom

I am using PHP and PHP Simple HTML Dom to get a link and download a csv file. However, the link is through a javascript call. Is there a way to get this through a PHP call or even wget through linux cmd? I am trying to get the spreadsheet through the Download Data link in the bottom right of the table.

Currently, I scrape the link by:

```
    <?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

//first we want to rip the data from pregame.com
$html =  file_get_html('http://pregame.com/sportsbook_spy/default.aspx');

$ret = $html->find('a');
$link=$ret[98]->attr['href'];


?>
```

Comment: That's an aspx doPostBack action. Here's an example of [handling doPostBack actions in php](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/introducing-pgbrowser.html).

Comment: Its not a form though?

Comment: It actually is if you look closer. The doPostBack javascript action sets values and then submits a form.